# How can I implement a mapping table in JSLT?

Tags: json, jslt

That is, for each possible value in a specific field in the incoming JSON I want to map to some new value. But those values are not predictable, so I need a mapping table. How can I express this in JSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to write the mapping table as a JSON object, and then use the `get-key` function. So something like this:

```
let mapping = {
  "foo" : 1,
  "bar" : 2,
  // ...
  "baz" : 24
}

{ "new-field" : get-key($mapping, .field) }
```

For the input `{"field" : "bar"}` you'll output `{"new-field" : 2}`.